# How do I tell my wifi device to stick to a channel

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng

I'm doing the usual exercises with airodump-ng, aireplay-ng etc. When I try to perform a fake authentication to a WEP protected wifi network I get the message quite frequently that I'm sending on channel X but the AP is on channel Y. I have set the wifi device into monitor mode with

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

and then I have tried to set the interface to the correct channel with

```
ifconfig wlan0 channel Y
```

but when I execute

```
iwlist wlan0 frequency
```

I can see that the device keeps hopping through the different channels. This means that I have to resubmit my attack commands many many times until coincidentally the device is on the correct channel when I'm submitting my command. There must be a way to tell the device to stop hopping but I can't find anything...

**Update**
I didn't say I use an Ubuntu computer. Is it the network manager doing this maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by purchasing a USB wireless adapter and working in a VM guest kali environment with that adapter. There I do a

```
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

and this preserves the session for the entire monitoring session. I presume in Ubuntu killing all the annoying processes doesn't have exactly the same effect as in kali.